# Haskell - zip alternative

Tags: haskell

I have written the following function:

```
f :: String -> [(Int, Int)] 
f s = zip x y where
  x = g s 
  y = h s
```

The function `g` has the following signature:

```
g :: String -> [Int]
```

and `h`:

```
h :: String -> [Int]
```

I want to modify `f` so it that it returns `[(Int, Int, String)]`, where `String` is its input `s`. I think the problem here is that zip strictly works on two lists. How can I do this?

Comment: You could use explicit recursion. Or another application of `zip` combined with a function you can easily write which converts a nested pair of type `((a, b), c)` into a triple `(a, b, c)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) and thus use an arbitrary function that takes elements from the two lists, and produces a value.

In this specific case, we can for example use a lambda expression:

```
f :: String -> [(Int, Int, String)]
f s = zipWith (\xi yi -> (xi, yi, s)) (g s) (h s)
```

Or you can make use of the [**`TupleSections`** extension [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TupleSections), and implement this as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

f :: String -> [(Int, Int, String)]
f s = zipWith (,,s) (g s) (h s)
```

Comment: This gives me a "parse error in pattern: \ yi -> (xi, yi, s)"

Comment: @iMazing: sorry, there was a backslash too much :)

Comment: How about `zip3 (g s) (h s) (repeat s)`